# ASP MVC Access ViewData Array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I have some viewdata that is generated by going through my repository to the database to grab some scheduling info. When the information is stored in the Viewdata, I noticed that the viewdata is enumerated. How could I access the enumerated items and generate a table/list based on the viewdata? Most of the information just needs to be spit out into a table, but one item will have a link generated for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know really understand what you mean when you say that *the viewdata is enumerated*. The ViewData contains instances of objects that you put inside your controller action. If you put an instance of an `IEnumerable<T>` you could enumerate. So let's suppose that you store an `IEnumerable<ProductViewData>` inside your ViewData from the controller action that's rendering the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["products"] = new[]
    {
        new ProductViewData { Id = 1, Description = "product 1" },
        new ProductViewData { Id = 2, Description = "product 2" },
        new ProductViewData { Id = 3, Description = "product 3" },
    }
    return View();
}
```

Inside the view you could enumerate and generate a table:

```
<table>
<% foreach (ProductViewData product in (IEnumerable<ProductViewData>)ViewData["products"]) { %>
<tr>
  <td><%= product.Id %></td>
  <td><%= Html.Encode(product.Description) %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

That being said you, I would recommend you to never do this and always use strongly typed views. Using `ViewData` requires you to cast and use magic strings inside your views which IMHO is bad.

Here's the same using a strongly typed view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new[]
    {
        new ProductViewData { Id = 1, Description = "product 1" },
        new ProductViewData { Id = 2, Description = "product 2" },
        new ProductViewData { Id = 3, Description = "product 3" },
    });
}
```

and the view:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNamespace.ProductViewData>" %>

<table>
<% foreach (var product in Model) { %>
<tr>
  <td><%= product.Id %></td>
  <td><%= Html.Encode(product.Description) %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

and things get even more promising when you start using HTML helpers in [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) such as the [Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid):

```
<%= Html.Grid<ProductViewData>(Model)
    .Columns(column => {
        column.For(model => model.Id);
        column.For(model => model.Description);
    })
%>
```

Comment: A strongly-typed view definitely sounds better. But I am not sure how to display a list of data from my model that is only after a certain date.

Comment: Make the controller or the model do the filtering of the view model.